# picture fallback default to png instead of webp

Tags: html, css

I have this problem here:

```
        <picture>
          <source
            srcset="/img/logoWebp/ebay.webp" type="image/webp"
          />
          <img
            alt="ebay"
            type="image/png"
            src="/img/logoPng/ebay.png"
          />
    </picture>
```

I have readed with this markup the browser should use the webP image but its using the png one. I am using ofcorse the lastes version of chrome.

Whats the probel here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i have found it out. It worked all the time just my dev tools kinda "trolled" me.
I thought it was png, but if i take a closer look it says `currentSrc:`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `<picture>` element contains two tags: one or more `<source>` tags and one `<img>` tag.

The browser will look for the first `<source>` element where the media query matches the current viewport width, and then it will display the proper image (specified in the srcset attribute). The `<img>` element is required as the last child of the `<picture>` element, as a fallback option if none of the source tags matches.

**Example:**

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg">
</picture>
```

When the width is greater than 650px, `img_orange_flowers.jpg` is displayed.

When the width is less than 650px and greater than 465px, `img_pink_flowers.jpg` is displayed.

When the width is less than 465px, `img_white_flowers.jpg` is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same "issue". "Current Source" showed me it was actually webp and not png as I though in the first place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).