# Chrome prefers jpg instead of Webp

Tags: html, image, jpeg, webp, fallback

I have a lot of `image/webp` images and want the browser to have a fallback `image/jpg` for Safari.

For some reason Chrome (and every other browser) is still using the jpg image instead of the webp.

```
<picture>
     <source class="content_image" height="150" width="150" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/pictures/section/logo_dsv_150x150.webp" type="image/webp">
     <source class="content_image" height="150" width="150" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/pictures/section/logo_dsv_150x150.png" type="image/png">
     <img height="150" width="150" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/pictures/section/logo_dsv_150x150.png" alt="lorem ipsum">
</picture>
```

I also have it in combination with ACF:

```
<?php
     $image_02_jpg = get_field('content_picture_02_jpg');
     $image_02_webp = get_field('content_picture_02_webp');
?>
<picture>
     <source class="content_image" width="679" height="450px" src="<?php echo $image_02_webp['url']; ?>" type="image/webp">
     <source class="content_image" width="679" height="450px" src="<?php echo $image_02_jpg['url']; ?>" type="image/jpeg"> 
     <img class="content_image" width="679" height="450px" src="<?php echo $image_02_jpg['url']; ?>" alt="content_image">
</picture>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487066/chrome-is-defaulting-to-jpg-when-webp-is-available-why

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312543/why-google-chrome-loads-jpg-instead-of-avif-and-webp

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700342/picture-fallback-default-to-png-instead-of-webp

Comment: @NicoHaase all of the links you are adding relate to where images are selected based on the `media` attribute. There is no `media` attribute in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `srcset` attribute instead of `src` on the `source` element.

```
<?php
  $image_02_jpg = get_field('content_picture_02_jpg');
  $image_02_webp = get_field('content_picture_02_webp');
?>
<picture>
  <source srcset="<?php echo $image_02_webp['url']; ?>" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="<?php echo $image_02_jpg['url']; ?>" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="<?php echo $image_02_jpg['url']; ?>" alt="content_image">
</picture>
```

[<source> Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)

- **src**: Required for <audio> and <video>, address of the media resource. **The value of this attribute is ignored when the <source> element is placed inside a <picture> element.**
- **srcset**: A list of one or more strings separated by commas indicating a set of possible images represented by the source for the browser to use.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you very much! this is fixing it! <3

Comment: But Google Pagespeed is still telling me to use modern img formats. any idea?

Edit: sry was just the cache. its fine now :)